# How many configuration files in a Spring project?

Tags: java, spring

How many config files would we generally write in a medium sized Spring project? And on what basis do we decide that we should configure it in separate file?

Comment: Your question is very open, please be specific.

Comment: How long is a piece of string? Heck, how big is *"medium sized"*?

Comment: web-layer, database-layer, security and so on...

Comment: You can add as many configuration files in project is totally upto you.

Comment: This is (as told by other commenters) not a good question. Even if it would... It would better fit to Software Engineering SE, wouldn't it?

Answer (score -1):

At least applicationContext.xml is required for bean configuration,view resolver etc.. Other than this you can add more configuration file to add like AOP and all.

Comment: Try to provide a clear and complete answer. Otherwise, put this into the comment section.